# I don’t understand why the correct example given in the book Java Generics and Collections obeys the Principle of Truth in Advertising

Tags: java

I think that I understand the concept itself: the reified type of an array must be a subtype of the erasure of its static type. But I feel that looking around for help has only confused me more. Here's my understanding of it and why I'm confused.

Here is some code that converts a `Collection<T>` to an array of type `T`.

```
//This code is taken straight from the book Java Generics and Collections
import java.util.*;
class Wrong {
    public static <T> T[] toArray(Collection<T> c) {
        T[] a = (T[])new Object[c.size]; // unchecked cast
        int i=0; for (T x : c) a[i++] = x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
       String[] a = toArray(strings); //class cast error
    }
}
```

A ClassCastException is thrown. At compile time, erasure converts all occurrences of type  `T` into type `Object` (because they have no bounds; if they did, they would be converted into their leftmost bound), converts parametric types into their raw types, and adds appropriate casts. So effectively, the code is equivalent to:

```
import java.util.*;
class Wrong {
   public static Object[] toArray(Collection c) {
      Object[] a = (Object[])new Object[c.size]; // unchecked cast
      int i=0; for (Object x : c) a[i++] = x;
      return a;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     List strings = Arrays.asList(args);
     String[] a = (String[])toArray(strings); //class cast error
   }
}
```

Since the method `toArray` effectively returns an `Object[]`, casting it to a `String[]` is illegal. In this case, the reified type of the array is `Object` while the erasure of its static type is  `String`, disobeying the principle.

If I understand this correctly, it seems to me that this code should also fail, but actually works without error.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Right {
    public static <T> T[] toArray(Collection<T> c, T[] a) {
        if (a.length < c.size())
            a = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.
                    newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), c.size());
        int i=0; for (T x : c) a[i++] = x;
        if(i < a.length) a[i] = null;
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
        String[] a = toArray(strings, new String[0]);
        assert Arrays.toString(a).equals("[one, two]");
        String[] b = new String[] {"x","x","x","x"};
        toArray(strings, b);
        assert Arrays.toString(b).equals("[one, two, null, x]");
    }
}
```

But following the first example, at compile time, through erasure, wouldn't all occurrences of type `T` be converted to type `Object`, parametric types be converted to raw types, and appropriate casts inserted just like the first example?
This is what I think it'd look like:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Right {
    public static Object[] toArray(Collection c, Object[] a) {
        if (a.length < c.size())
            a = (Object[])java.lang.reflect.Array.
                    newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), c.size());
        int i=0; for (Object x : c) a[i++] = x;
        if(i < a.length) a[i] = null;
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
        String[] a = (String[])toArray(strings, new String[0]); //class cast exception?????
        assert Arrays.toString(a).equals("[one, two]");
        String[] b = new String[] {"x","x","x","x"};
        toArray(strings, b); /*I think this would be fine because the Principle of Truth in 
                               Advertising is followed within the method body. It's just a problem
                               when attempting to assign the return value of this method within 
                               the main method*/
        assert Arrays.toString(b).equals("[one, two, null, x]");
    }
}
```

But I assume that's not actually what's happening? To be clear, I feel that the cast to `T[]` on line 5 in both examples is what's causing the issue, as through erasure, `T[]` becomes `Object[]`. So, the array `a` is effectively of type `Object[]`.

I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding about reification or erasure, or maybe something else. I've looked around online and no explanation has been able to satisfy my question, so answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @StephenC  In the book, Java Generics and Collection there are nine, discontiguous pages (idientified in the index under that phrase) where the authors discuss that.  The OP was being serious and I believe a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

> So, the array a is effectively of type Object[].

Nope.

There is no array a. Objects don't have names; variables have names. `a` is a variable. It points at an object. That doesn't mean that object's name is a:

```
Object a = "foo";
Object b = a;
a = null;
```

So, should we call `"foo"` a or b? Neither: Objects do not have names.

a is a variable and its type is effectively `Object[]`, sure. It's pointing at an object, and that object's type (not 'effective type', objects don't have an 'effective' type. they have an actual type) is `String[]` in your second snippet, and `Object[]` in the first. THAT is the crucial difference: That ClassCastException occurs in the first snippet because the *actual* type is not compatible.

Why is this so? Because `new T[]` gets boiled down in java code to making a new object (hence the `new`), and as T is erased, the newly created object's actual type will be `Object[]`. However, in the second snippet, the reflection shenanigans means the newly created array is *actually* of type `String[]`.. and is then assigned to `a`, which is a variable of type `Object[]`. Which doesn't make type sense (`List<Object> x = new ArrayList<String>()` does not work; you can add Integer objects to a list of objects, which is not a legal move here), but the java spec explicitly says that you can assign any array of any reference type to `Object[]` anyway, because arrays in java are broken.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I understand that the reflection methods create a new instance of an array that is indeed of type `String[]`. However, it's being put into an array of type `Object[]` (through erasure), and _that's_ what's being returned, correct? If so, wouldn't the ClassCastException still be thrown due to the code trying to cast variable `a` of type `Object[]` to type `String[]`?

Comment: _However, it's being put into an array of type Object[] (through erasure)_ <-- I think you just don't understand yet how java works. `Object[] a;` __is not an array__. It is __a variable__, and it's always a pointer. It's like the array is the house, and 'a' is merely a page in an address book. `a = new String[10]` means: Build a house. It has no name and never will. Then, find the address book page titled 'a', and write in pencil the address of the house you just built on it. a isn't the house - it's just a simple little note you can use to walk over to it.

Comment: PlaceToSleep a = new Caravan();` means: There is one caravan. There is also an address book page, with an address to this caravan, and that address book page states that if there is an address written on this page at all, it will lead to some place you can sleep. Could be a caravan, could be a house. It doesn't magically turn that caravan into an abstract 'sleep here' concept. It's still a caravan.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, I see, the caravan concept really helped. Thanks for explaining it to me!

Comment: I actually am in need for a bit more clarification regarding the cast to ```T[]``` on line 5 for both snippets. At compile time, does the cast become a cast to ```Object[]``` through erasure?

Comment: @PietroLinguini At compile time? It does _nothing_ at compile time. It's java-ese for: "Hey, compiler? Shut up. I know what I am doing, compile this, I'll eat the risk of runtime exceptions". It doesn't compile to anything at all. (A normal cast, e.g. `(String) y`, compiles to almost nothing: a CHECKCAST opcode which does nothing if y is a string, and throws CCEx if y is not - that one too is mostly just you telling the compiler how to interpret other lines).

Comment: So what's causing the issue is **only** the reified type of the array after erasure? Does the fact that after erasure, the return type of the method is `Object[]` or that the array that variable `a` is pointing to is being cast to type `Object[]`?

Comment: Yup. The return type of the method is irrelevant, casts are irrelevant (they throw CCEx or do nothing), and types of variables are irrelevant. Just the actual type of the actual object; what `a.getClass()` returns.